# How can I remove files from a QtCreator project

Tags: qt-creator

Might be a very newbie question, but I can't find a way to remove files from my projects in QtCreator. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If your project is generated from CMake, the file list is determined by the CMakeLists.txt file, and you cannot add or remove files manually from the source tree in QtCreator.  Especially if your CMakeLists file specifies the glob operator for a project's file list, you must manually remove the files from disk and re-run CMake *from within QtCreator* by going to Build->Run CMake (QtCreator 3.3.0).  This will update the file list but also regenerate the project (cbp) file - re-running CMake outside of QtCreator will not update the project file and you will have ghost entries of deleted files showing up in the source tree if you deleted them from disk.

Comment: The question is, why doesn't Qt creator do this automatically?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't want Qt creator changing my cmake code behind the scenes, so deleting the file from the filesystem is at best going to be a half-measure that doesn't really achieve the objective. Some notification to this effect would be helpful though.

Comment: had this issue, doing it manually fixed my project tree

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the file you want to remove, and choose "Remove File..."

Checking the "Delete file permanently" check box will delete the file, otherwise it will just be removed from the project.

Comment: Ah didn't find it either, you have to delete the files and not the folders.

Comment: And if "Remove File..." is disabled?

Comment: Be warned that this option still deletes files (at least on Windows) even if you have the box unchecked. It's not in my recycle bin either.

Comment: The `Remove File...` option might be disabled, because the file is from a different project AND that project is not ocrrectly configured. In that case it should be contained in a project folder higher up in the tree. You can right-click that folder and choose `Close project "project name"`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your project file .pro in qt creator or other text editor
2. Find the file/folder name you want to remove in the .pro file
3. Delete all the files you want to remove
4. save and close the project
5. Reload the project
6. DONE

Answer (score 0):

Could not find one-touch action as in Eclipse to delete a class:

1) Press right click on the file/class, and then choose "remove file..."; (u can tick "permanently" to remove from HDD if you like).

2) Do it to .CPP and .H files.

3) Then check in your .pro file the class are not there anymore.

Note: Some compilers will keep searching for this file/class in compilation. Just delete the compilation directory and compile again.

Comment: Thanks! Deleting the build directory is definitely necessary when using MSVC2010. I was wondering why it was still looking for files no longer mentioned anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you mess up like me and accidentally add a lot of files to the `qml.qrc`, it might help to know that these are listed in the actual `qml.qrc` file which you can edit to remove these files.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this problem.

I wanted to remove a header file.
But remove action in context menu was disabled I didn't know why.

The file name was `qtextdocument.h`.
I wanted to change the name to `textdocument.h`.

I tried to do various ways, but the filename was strictly fixed.

My removal procedure was as follows:

1. I dare to add an empty file to the file directory (in header file directory).
   Anyway, I set the file name as `textdocument.h` when Qt Creator asked me to set the filename.
2. A confirmation warning popped up.
   (Qt Creator cannot add the file automatically, we must add the file name to CMakeTextLists.txt)
3. I changed the filename in CMakeTextLists.txt from 'qtextdocument.h' to 'textdocument.h' in the row of set(PROJECT_SOURCES).
4. Finally, the update was confirmed. 'qtextdocument.h' was removed and the name is changed to 'textdocument.h'.

If you only want to remove a file, only you have to do is to delete the filename when you are in step 3.

After updating the project tree, the actual file is in your computer.

If you want to delete the file completely, you select  **file system** and remove the file, not from **project**.

[image]

I don't know why, but in the case of filesystem mode, remove action is enabled.
So I might & should have told you that you select "filesystem mode" and remove the file at the first time...
(Sorry  I have found out this fact later.)

Both of the two ways, I think we must rewrite the contents of CMakeTextLists.txt.

I also run into the case ,  the update removed the filename as soon as I deleted the filename from `CMakeTextLists.txt`.

I believe this case I directly make a file in the actual directory. On the contrary, above case is the files are added from Project menus.

Answer (score -1):

go directly delete the project folder from your hdd.

Answer (score -1):

For Linux, edit ~/.config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini

Under [ProjectExplorer], delete the project name and its corresponding configuration file from the following two lists:

RecentProjects\DisplayNames
RecentProjects\FileNames

e.g., given the following
RecentProjects\DisplayNames=proj1, proj2, proj3
RecentProjects\FileNames=<proj1_dir>/CMakeLists.txt, <proj2_dir>/proj2.pro, <proj3_dir>/proj3.pro

to delete proj1 from the qtcreator startup page, edit the above two lists as

RecentProjects\DisplayNames=proj2, proj3
RecentProjects\FileNames=<proj2_dir>/proj2.pro, <proj3_dir>/proj3.pro

Comment: That apparently just temporarily removes the project from the startup page - at least for the CMakeLists.txt case. The CMakeCache.txt also had entries for the project name but even after deleting those, it re-created the project name so it reappeared on the start page

Comment: Ahh - because that's the project name in CMakeLists.txt ; so any time I selected CMakeLists.txt to create a new project it gives it that name.

Comment: This is not what the original post was asking for. (But it was what I was looking for - thanks.)